# Regular expression to restrict characters to 6

Tags: regex, validation, restrict

I need a regular expression to validate the text in a particular format Eg: `VT-ABC`

This particular regular expression should start with `VT-` followed by 3 alphabet letters. The whole string should contain exactly 6 characters.

I tried the regular expression `^[V][T][-][A-Z]{6}`, but this is not working.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you defined "not working" ? - you say maximum of 6, but {6} means *exactly* 6... {0,6} would mean between 0-6

Comment: Do you mean "max. six characters in all" or "three to six letters after `VT-`, not more"?

Comment: maximum of 6 characters in all.i.e) 3 letters after VT-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an end-of-string [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), and of course only three letters should be allowed, not six:

```
^VT-[A-Z]{3}$
```

Comment: @lakshganga Note that this will only match a string of exactly 6 characters. In your question you stated a **maximum** of 6 characters.